# Convert text into number using which formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to convert my values into numbers, so I can add hem together, but I can't find any right formula for these numbers.

These are some of the number:

```
2 997
1 500
1 500
0
1 800
2 500
0
0
0
98 923,5
0
0
```

This mask is not working: # ##0,00, the SUM method showing me 0 as result :(

Expected result for these number:

```
2 997
1 500
1 500
0
1 800
2 500
0
0
0
98 923,5
0
0
```

they are formatted as:

```
2997,00
1500,00
1500,00
0,00
1800,00
2500,00
0,00
0,00
0,00
98923,50
0,00
0,00
```

And the SUM should be giving me: 109200 (if I calculated right...)

Comment: Remove the mask. They should work directly

Comment: I tried with the simple "number" cell format, but the SUM is still 0, so this way it's nor working :(

Comment: probably you aren't summing right.

Comment: =SUM(H2:H13) isn't right?

Comment: applying formatting to a cell does not change the contents of a cell.  If you have 0.5 as the value of the cell and you change the format from general to time, it will display as 12:00 noon, but the content of the cell is still 0.5.  Similarly if a number is entered as text, it remains as text even if you change the formatting to numerical, general, financial etc.  One of the easiest ways to change a number stored as text is to send it through a math operator (not a function).  In your case you will need to make your number match your system settings I suspect.

Comment: Just do what I do when invited to weddings and plus zero. (`+0`). That'll turn it into a value.

Comment: Where excatly do I need to type this in and make this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following array formula to clear spaces and sum all the cells:

```
=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A1:A80<>0,A1:A80)," ","")))
```

Remember to press Crtl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter to complete the formula and get the brackets {} so it looks like:

```
{=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A1:A80<>0,A1:A80)," ","")))}
```

Note: the range here is A1:A80, change it to where the values are.

Comment: How can I execute this on macOS with Office 365?